# How to create a video file webm from chunks by media recorder api using ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ffmpeg, chunks

I'm trying to create a webm video file from blobs generated by MediaRecorderAPI in a NodeJS server using FFMPEG. I'm able to create the *.webm* file but it's not playable, I ran this command `$ ffmpeg.exe -v error -i lel.webm -f null - >error.log 2>&1`   to generate an error log, the error log file contains this:

> [null @ 000002ce7501de40] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 1 >= 1
>
> [h264 @ 000002ce74a727c0] Invalid NAL unit size (804 > 74).
>
> [h264 @ 000002ce74a727c0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
>
> Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

This is my web server code

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const fs = require("fs");
const child_process = require("child_process");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");

  const ffmpeg = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i",
    "-",
    "-vcodec",
    "copy",
    "-f",
    "flv",
    "rtmpUrl.webm",
  ]);

  ffmpeg.on("close", (code, signal) => {
    console.log(
      "FFmpeg child process closed, code " + code + ", signal " + signal
    );
  });

  ffmpeg.stdin.on("error", (e) => {
    console.log("FFmpeg STDIN Error", e);
  });

  ffmpeg.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("FFmpeg STDERR:", data.toString());
  });

  socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log("Writing blob! ");
    ffmpeg.stdin.write(msg);
  });

  socket.on("stop", () => {
    console.log("Stop recording..");
    ffmpeg.kill("SIGINT");
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

And this is my client code, using HTML, JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io();
    let mediaRecorder = null;
    const startRecording = (someStream) => {
      const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
      const videoTrack = someStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      const audioTrack = someStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
      console.log("Video trac ", videoTrack);
      console.log("audio trac ", audioTrack);
      mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
      mediaStream.addTrack(audioTrack);

      const recorderOptions = {
        mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=h264",
        videoBitsPerSecond: 3 * 1024 * 1024,
      };

      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, recorderOptions);
      mediaRecorder.start(1000); // 1000 - the number of milliseconds to record into each Blob
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        console.debug("Got blob data:", event.data);
        if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
          socket.emit("message", event.data);
        }
      };
    };

    const getVideoStream = async () => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true,
        });
        startRecording(stream);
        myVideo.srcObject = stream;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("navigator.getUserMedia error:", e);
      }
    };

    const stopRecording = () => {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      socket.emit("stop");
    };
  </script>
  <body>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <button onclick="getVideoStream()">start rec</button>
    <button onclick="stopRecording()">stop rec</button>

    <video width="300" height="300" autoplay id="myvideo" />
    <script>
      const myVideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
      myVideo.muted = true;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are encoding into flv, not webm. So you have flv encoded video inside the webm container - which the playback device just has no idea what to do with :)

Try the command above on just an mp4 on your computer - I bet it will not work.  To encode into webm - check out these [ffmpeg commands](https://gist.github.com/Vestride/278e13915894821e1d6f)

Comment: thankss, after posting I just figured it out, what a silly mistake haha, anyway thank you very much!